# Getting notification when one event is not fired for a specific amount of time

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

In my winform application i am raising one event frequently. If that event is not raised for more than 2 minutes i need to display a message to the user.

Can anyone help me ragarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You've already tagged your question with timer tag. Use timer 8) Start it on first event occasion. Then use some static bool flag in event that would marker that event occurred. Check for flag in Timer Tick event. If its true - then ok. If false then not ok. Then false flag in Tick event.